# MVC3 Razor - Models and Views

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, model, view, partial

I have an action that creates a List and returns it to my view..

```
public ActionResult GetCustomers()
    {
        return PartialView("~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/Customers.cshtml", UserQueries.GetCustomers(SiteInfo.Current.Id));
    }
```

And in the "~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/Customers.cshtml" view I have the following:

```
@model IEnumerable<FishEye.Models.CustomerModel>
@Html.DisplayForModel("Customer")
```

Then I have in the "~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/Customer.cshtml" view:

```
@model FishEye.Models.CustomerModel
@Model.Profile.FirstName
```

I am getting the error:

```
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Models.CustomerModel]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'Models.CustomerModel'.
```

Shouldn't it display the Customer.cshtml for every item in the collection in the Customers.cshtml?

Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why you are calling a partial view like this. If it is a Customer Specific view, why not put it under `Views/Customer` folder ? Remember ASP.NET MVC is more of **Conventions**. so i would always stick with the conventions (unless abosultely necessary to configure myself) to keep it simple.

To handle this situation, i would do it in this way,

a `Customer` and `CustomerList` model/Videmodel

```
public class CustomerList
{
    public List<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    //Other Properties as you wish also
}

public class Customer
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And in the action method, i would return an object of CustomerList class

```
CustomerList customerList = new CustomerList();
customerList.Customers = new List<Customer>();
customerList.Customers.Add(new Customer { Name = "Malibu" });
// you may replace the above manual adding with a db call.
return View("CustomerList", customerList);
```

Now there should be a view called `CustomerList.cshtml` under `Views/YourControllerName/` folder. That view should look like this

```
@model CustomerList
<p>List of Customers</p>
@Html.DisplayFor(x=>x.Customers)
```

Have a view called `Customer.cshtml` under `Views/Shared/DisplayTemplate`s with this content

```
@model Customer
<h2>@Model.Name</h2>
```

This will give you the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

Your view is expecting a single model:

```
@model FishEye.Models.CustomerModel  // <--- Just one of me
```

You're passing it an anonymous List:

```
... , UserQueries.GetCustomers(SiteInfo.Current.Id)  // <--- Many of me
```

You should change your view to accept the List or determine which item in the list is supposed to be used before passing it into the View. Keep in mind, a list with 1 item is still a list and the View is not allowed to guess.